# Re-instating indenting and line spacing in LaTeX template

Tags: indentation

I'm using the template http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis, which I think is great. However, this template has somehow been set up to make bigger line spacing instead of indenting paragraphs, and I can't figure out how. I would like to go back to indenting and not line spacing. Does someone know how to change this?

Note: There are some \parskip and \parindent commands in the .cls file, but they seem to be for special sections of the paper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class indeed sets zero parindent and a nonzero parskip. Moreover it uses `vmargin` which is known to be incompatible with some packages, notably `atbegshi` which is used by various others.

I suggest you to modify it, changing lines from 66 to 89; here's the original (with line numbers for reference):

```
 66 \usepackage{setspace}
 67 \onehalfspacing
 68 \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
 69 \setlength{\parskip}{2.0ex plus0.5ex minus0.2ex}
 70 \usepackage{vmargin}
 71 %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 72 %       MARGINS
 73 %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 74 \setmarginsrb  { 1.5in}  % left margin
 75                         { 0.6in}  % top margin
 76                         { 1.0in}  % right margin
 77                         { 0.8in}  % bottom margin
 78                         {  20pt}  % head height
 79                         {0.25in}  % head sep
 80                         {   9pt}  % foot height
 81                         { 0.3in}  % foot sep
 82 %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 83 \raggedbottom
 84 \setlength{\topskip}{1\topskip \@plus 5\p@}
 85 \doublehyphendemerits=10000       % No consecutive line hyphens.
 86 \brokenpenalty=10000              % No broken words across columns/pages.
 87 \widowpenalty=9999                % Almost no widows at bottom of page.
 88 \clubpenalty=9999                 % Almost no orphans at top of page.
 89 \interfootnotelinepenalty=9999    % Almost never break footnotes.
```

Here's the modified code

```
%%% Uncomment the following two lines if you really want doublespacing
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{includehead,includefoot,
  left=1.5in,
  top=0.6in,
  right=1.0in,
  bottom=0.8in,
  headheight=20pt,
  headsep=0.25in,
  footskip=0.3in}

\doublehyphendemerits=10000       % No consecutive line hyphens.
\brokenpenalty=10000              % No broken words across columns/pages.
\widowpenalty=9999                % Almost no widows at bottom of page.
\clubpenalty=9999                 % Almost no orphans at top of page.
\@clubpenalty=9999                % Almost no orphans at top of page.
\interfootnotelinepenalty=9999    % Almost never break footnotes.
```

**Comments**

1. Double spacing is *bad*, avoid it if you can.
2. `vmargin` is not to be used.
3. Setting a flexible `\topskip` is a quite bad idea.
4. The final settings of the penalty parameters may seem a good idea, but it's not. However, I didn't touch them, except adding the setting of `\@clubpenalty`, which is the *real* parameter in LaTeX for controlling orphan lines.
5. `\raggedbottom` in a twosided document is not recommendable.