# Thesis paper format and bibliography issues!

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, paper-size

I'll try to be as clear as possible.
I use texshop 2.47 on my Mac with bibdesk. So far I wrote an article for ACS journal with their package. At the moment I'm working on my PhD thesis. I found this nice template which is using:

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, openright, twoside]{Thesis}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
```

The template is really well done. So I got two main problems:
- I can't generate a5 .pdf (if I write a5paper the pdf is still a4 for some reason)
- The bibliography is generated correctly but also shows me doi, url and title, which I don't want.

Now I've been reading a bit, most people suggest to switch to BibLaTeX or others.
I personally don't want to play too much around with it, but I thought there must be a simple solution. The way I would like to generate the pdf is in a5 format (so I see how it looks when it will be printed) and with the several references with full authors list (not Smith et al.) and all the other information (except title, doi, url).

The authors of this template create a `thesis.cls` which can be found here (http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis)

EDIT: `\documentclass[11pt, b5paper, openright, twoside]{Thesis}
\usepackage[square,numbers,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}`

and

`\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{Bibliography}`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Side comment: it is usually a bad idea to have commands before  `\documentclass`, unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: The class you're using doesn't support different paper sizes. You can look at [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102376/4427) where I suggested some changes to it, in particular for the page parameters. You can play with the suggested options to the `\geometry` command, adding also `a5paper`.

Comment: If the problem is the class Thesis, then I should better stay away from it. I did edit as egreg suggest in this post[http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102373/re-instating-indenting-and-line-spacing-in-latex-template/102376#102376] the thesis.cls! Now give me some error due to this commands which are repeated few times in the main.tex `\setstretch{1.3}` so i just uncomment all of those.

Comment: To omit the DOI and ISSN fields from inclusion in the printouts, see the following answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50960/5001.

Comment: @Mico i search for that file without success, so i create one name it as you suggested and by leaving the .bst file in the same folder as the main.tex it DOES work. No DOI, URL etc etc.

Comment: @DavideF. - If you can't locate `unsrtnat.bst` on your computer's hard disk, you can always download it from, say, http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib.

Comment: I don't thin is a big deal, because the bibliography compile well, however i got this message in the console for every reference:You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry angello
while executing---line 1303 of file unsrtnatdna.bst

Comment: If I may add to the same post a further question: I've seen quite few post in the web about this but no clear answer for my config. I have as the template provides several Chapter.tex, one main.tex and one bibliography.bib! For my thesis I must have the bibliography at the end of each chapter. I would be very glad any of you could provide a simple way to do it (since my latex skill are still low)

Comment: Without a proper MWE and I suspect a focus on one issue per question I don't think this will get answered. Please edit and request reopening.