# Subcaption Package Error

Tags: captions, subfloats, templates, subcaption

I'm having an issue compiling with the subcaption package. I'm starting to write my thesis, and I originally started a chapter with a separate document. This compiled fine and had the following pre-amble

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage,graphicx,amsmath,verbatim,float,caption,subcaption}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\begin{document}
```

I then moved to a template for a thesis, (full template is here http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template/ ) I copied across the chapter I have completed into the chapter1.tex file as specified. I also copied across my \usepackage line to give the following preamble in the thesis document:

```
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
%% Thesis.tex -- MAIN FILE (the one that you compile with LaTeX)
%% ---------------------------------------------------------------- 

% Set up the document
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{Thesis}  % Use the "Thesis" style, based on the            ECS Thesis style by Steve Gunn
\graphicspath{{Figures/}}  % Location of the graphics files (set up for graphics to be     in PDF format)

% Include any extra LaTeX packages required
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  % Use the "Natbib" style    for the references in the Bibliography
\usepackage{verbatim}  % Needed for the "comment" environment to make LaTeX comments
\usepackage{vector}  % Allows "\bvec{}" and "\buvec{}" for "blackboard" style bold vectors in maths
\usepackage{fullpage,graphicx,amsmath,float,caption,subcaption}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true}  % Colours hyperlinks in blue, but this can   be distracting if there are many links.
```

When I compile the Thesis.tex file it now has three errors for each of the figures I'm trying to use

1. ! Use of \@subfloat doesn't match its definition.
2. ! Missing number, treated as zero.
3. ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).

An example of the code for one of my figures is as follows:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{figure1}
        \caption{figure1 caption}
        \label{fig: figure1 }
    \end{subfigure}
    \hspace{20mm}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{figure2}
        \caption{figure2 caption}
        \label{fig: figure2 }
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
```

If I remove the subfigure package then the file will compile, but the formatting is all screwed up. I'm guessing there are conflicting packages, but i can't find which one it is.

I'm pretty new to latex and just learning the ropes, so if it something silly then I apologise in advance.

Thanks in advance for any help

John

Comment: The `Thesis.cls` loads `subfigure`, which has been obsolete for at least ten years; it also loads `vmargin` which is incompatible with several packages. I wouldn't recommend using it.

Comment: I'm using the template by Steve Gunn as well and I had the same problem. Unless I'm mistaken, you'll also want to move `\usepackage{hyperref}` from `Thesis.cls` to just before `\begin{document}` in case you load a package that needs to come before it. (Are you a University of Southampton student by any chance? `:-)`)

Comment: Ah, I hadn't noticed that Thesis.cls loaded packages aswell!! I'll give it ago to see if I can get it working, If not I'll do the formatting myself. I'm actually a University of Newcastle Student :) probably as far away from Southampton in the UK you can get! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 7):

The class loads `subfigure` which conflicts with `subcaption` and has been obsolete for several years.

Remove the call of this package from the template. It should do no harm and will allow you to load and use `subcaption`.

---

Also the `vmargin` package that's used by the class has problems of compatibility with other packages, notably `atbegshi`; it's probably better two switch to `geometry` for setting the page parameters. You can find an example of conversion in [this answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102376/4427)

Comment: If i comment subfigure then i cant use subfigure ... so of course that is not a solution..